# Packet crafting and iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, raw-sockets

I want to test how the netfilter/ip6tables firewall handles some IPv6-related stuff like tiny/overlapped fragments, type 0 routing headers, excessive HPH options etc. For this I wanted to use Scapy to craft my own packets, but apparently Scapy using raw sockets means bypassing iptables. Is there another way of achieving my goal and how would I go about it? Some library I could use to make my own packets, which iptables can act on?

Answer (score 1):

Run your packet injection program from a VM, and inspect the network connected to that VM.

Scapy is useful for such odd tasks.  Sometimes what you want to do is just as easily done by writing small programs using the normal C APIs (including raw sockets in some cases, or TCP connections with odd options set).  In many cases, a trivial TCP or UDP client in any high level language such as Python will do.

Comment: Would you please elaborate on the VM thing? That's in fact what I was actually doing when trying out scapy, but I'm not sure how would it help with the raw sockets problem

Comment: You have one machine running iptables and another generating arbitrary packets with raw sockets.  They are connected by a common virtual network.  Tcpdump this network from the host to verify what is actually being sent from the raw sockets.  Now raw sockets and iptables issues are completely unrelated.